# How to update a column using min/max from a different column as conditional on hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

So given the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists my_data_base.stg (
    flag INT,
    incidence DATE);
insert into stg (flag, incidence) values (0, '2022-01-01'), (0, '2022-01-02'), (0, '2022-01-03'), (0, '2022-01-04');
```

I'd would like to change whichever row has the earliest date so that the flag column equals 1 while the rest stay the same, like this.

| Incidence | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | 0 |

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd bother doing this as part of the table data/keeping it up to date upon every insert, just calculate it at query time

Comment: Could you elaborate further? I'm just recently starting to learn hive.

Answer (score 1):

you really dont have to store the like this. But it depends on  your requirement.
When you are loading the data, you can calculate the column like this -

```
SELECT 
flag, case when rs.rn =1 then 1 else 0 end as incidence --stamp least row to 1
FROM
( select flag, row_number() over( order by flag ) rn -- ordering the data so to find least row 
 from my_data_base.stg) rs
```

OR Else, like comment said, You can use above SQL to stamp the record to 1.

Comment: I can't seem to make this work. I get the next error message: 

ParseException line 1:90 cannot recognize input near 'row_number' 'over' '(' in selection target,

Comment: sorry, there is a typo in the code. i fixed above answer

Comment: Thank you, I had already figured. My problema right now is that this query makes every entry in the incidence column equal to 0. I'm looking into it but if you could help me one more time I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: are you using my query or you built a new one? can you share ?

Comment: there should be only one row with incidence =1, rest all should be 0

Comment: Also i think flag data type in table is INT but in your example its date. you can check that out as well